# ffmpeg-normalize exits with OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: ffmpeg, python

I have a large number of files I want to normalize the volume with a simple method using a basic loop.

When trying to use ffmpeg-normalize the application exits with the error. I searched the error on-line but I can't find any issue similar to mine. I thought it may be a 'path' or file type association problem but they look ok.

Can anyone give me an explanation for this error and a possible fix for it please?

```
D:\Test>ffmpeg-normalize.exe in.mkv -o out.mkv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\les\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\les\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Les\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\ffmpeg-normalize.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\les\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\ffmpeg_normalize\__main__.py", line 409, in main
    ffmpeg_normalize = FFmpegNormalize(
  File "c:\users\les\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\ffmpeg_normalize\_ffmpeg_normalize.py", line 68, in __init__
    self.has_loudnorm_capabilities = ffmpeg_has_loudnorm()
  File "c:\users\les\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\ffmpeg_normalize\_cmd_utils.py", line 185, in ffmpeg_has_loudnorm
    cmd_runner.run_command()
  File "c:\users\les\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\ffmpeg_normalize\_cmd_utils.py", line 101, in run_command
    p = subprocess.Popen(
  File "c:\users\les\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "c:\users\les\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1416, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

D:\Test>path
PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Calibre2\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Calibre2\;C:\Users\Les\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\;C:\Users\Les\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\;C:\Users\Les\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;D:\MABS\local64\bin-video;C:\Program Files (x86)\sox-14-4-2

D:\Test>ftype python.file
python.file="C:\Users\Les\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe" "%1"

D:\Test>python.exe
Python 3.9.1 (tags/v3.9.1:1e5d33e, Dec  7 2020, 17:08:21) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version N-100483-g728b83a7c4-gd67c6c7f6f+4 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev6, Built by MSYS2 project)



 D:\Test>ffmpeg-normalize --version
        ffmpeg-normalize v1.22.1
```

Comment: In my system `ftype python.file` output is `python.file="C:\WINDOWS\py.exe" "%L" %*`. I Modifying the association by executing `ftype python.file="c:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe" "%1"`, but `ffmpeg-normalize.exe` is still working

Comment: Thanks - Rotem
I've just reinstalled  3.9 and my ftype is now:

    D:\Test>ftype python.file
    python.file="C:\Windows\py.exe" "%L" %*

Which is the same as yours. However  ffmpeg-normalize still fails with the same error message.
I've tried using ffmpeg with the loudnorm filter and 2 passes but it takes a long time for each file so doesn't really do what I want.

Comment: Try downloading the latest stable version of FFmpeg command line tool. Your version number looks like a "nightly build". In case it's not working, you can try installing Python 3.6 and executing `pip3 install ffmpeg-normalize` for Python 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same error. I had a ffmpeg version built using the "media-autobuild suite". Inside my ffmpeg install folder there was a standalone file named "ffmpeg". When typing "where ffmpeg" in the command prompt, it showed both "ffmpeg" and "ffmpeg.exe". The "ffmpeg" file is a bash script that I'm not sure what it does. I simply renamed the bash script file to something different and restarted my command prompt and the ffmpeg-normalize now worked without the error.